# going through JSON tree to get values then print to console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some example JSON...

```
{
 "colors": {
        "1": {
            "name": "red", 
            "rgb_value": "255,0,0"
        }, 
        "2": {
            "name": "green", 
            "rgb_value": "0,255,0"
        }, 
        "3": {
            "name": "blue", 
            "rgb_value": "0,0,255"
        }
    }
}
```

Question: I would like to know how to go into "colors" then check each object ("1", "2", "3"... etc) and get the value of "name" for each one (I would like to print each one to the console with console.log). How can I do this?

Either Javascript/jQuery solutions are appreciated.

Note I cannot change the JSON as I am taking it from someone's API and have no power to re-structure their JSON so if you don't think the JSON is right, please ignore it as I have no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.each()` to iterate through `colors` of your object and get the `name` value:

```
$.each(obj.colors, function(i, val) {
    console.log(obj.colors[i].name);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HfXfx/1/)**

Comment: thank you :) I will tick in 9 minutes when it says i can

Comment: Fist you should parse your JSON with JSON.parse function (if you need older browsers compatibility, use json2.js)

Comment: thank you Zoltan. amazingly i already knew how to do that part but thank you for posting in case someone else needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've parsed your JSON, a simple loop will suffice:

```
for (var k in obj.colors) {
  console.log(obj.colors[k].name);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44AAx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you. suppose your object name is data

```
var data = {
    "colors": {
        "1": {
            "name": "red", 
            "rgb_value": "255,0,0"
        }, 
        "2": {
            "name": "green", 
            "rgb_value": "0,255,0"
        }, 
        "3": {
            "name": "blue", 
            "rgb_value": "0,0,255"
        }
    }
}

for (key in data["colors"]) {
  console.log(data["colors"][key]["name"])
}
```

this time it is working now, you can copy and paste in javascript console and see the result

Comment: can you send me in the right direction to read about using [] like this? i am unsure how it works

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in JS. `Object.keys(obj.colors)` returns `["1","2","3"]` and `forEach()` loops through `obj.colors["1"]`, `obj.colors["2"]` and `obj.colors["3"]` logging the `name`'s value of each one of them.

```
Object.keys(obj.colors).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(obj.colors[key].name);
});
```